# I currently have the patent for the digit bandage and am wanting to sell it

Tags: sell

I have the patent of the digit bandage. My grandfather was William casey Jr. I would like to sell the patent

Answer (score 2):

[US2253108A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2253108A/en?oq=US2253108A) was granted on August 19, 1941 and expired  on August 19, 1958. This is the basic deal with patents. In return for a limited term of exclusivity, you teach the world how to use your invention. Once the term is up anyone can use it without payment. The patent is non-enforceable at this point so there is no potential for licensing. Although William Casey Jr. is listed as the inventor, the assignee is listed as William Jenkins so even if it weren't expired you don't have the right to license it (unless the assignment has changed again).

If you have the original document, there could possibly be some collectable value, but that is not within the scope of this site. Perhaps searching EBay for similar collectables will give you an idea of its value.

Beyond that, there hopefully is sentimental value. I certainly hope that my grandchildren learn their grandad was an inventor and had patents to prove it.